# rename folder name in dropbox using api php

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I want to **Rename Folder Name** on dropbox. Only rename the folder not move it to any other destination.
/home/ABC after /home/ACB

I want to change only "ABC" to  "ACB" any other name.
And thanks in advance for your reply and suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming on Dropbox is equivalent to a move (without changing the parent path). To move/rename a file or folder on Dropbox using the Dropbox API, you would use [the /2/files/move_v2 endpoint](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-move) (or corresponding method in an SDK/library).

For your example, for a folder named "ABC" inside a folder named "home", you would set `from_path="/home/ABC"` and `to_path="/home/ACB"`.

Comment: Thanks for guide its working fine @greg